# Why do we needed pickBy in Lodash when We can use delete operator instead?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have a small question.

Why do we needed `pickBy` in `Lodash` or similar? Just simple with `delete operator`.

```
// Input
const source = {
  user: {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Done"
  },
  password: "123"
};
```

```
// Output
const result = {
  user: {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Done"
  }
};
```

There are many ways to get the desired result:
**https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-rubin-xlj25k?file=/src/index.ts**

**With `pickBy`:**

```
const result = _.pickBy(
  source,
  (value, key) => !(key === "password" && value === "123")
);
```

**With native:**

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(source).filter(
    ([key, value]) => !(key === "password" && value === "123")
  )
);
```

**And with `delete operator`: Lightweight, fastest, no loop,...vv**

```
const result = Object.assign({}, source);
if (result.password === "123") {
  delete result.password;
}
```

So, I'm looking for reasons not to use `delete operator`.

---

**--UPDATED** for mutation issue:

All ways are mutated `user.firstname`

```
source.user.firstname = "New first name";
console.log({ source, result  });
```

```json
{
  "source": {
    "user": {
      "firstname": "New first name",
      "lastname": "Done"
    },
    "password": "123"
  },
  "result": {
    "user": {
      "firstname": "New first name",
      "lastname": "Done"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Lightweight, fastest, no loop,...vv

Sure, if you're deleting a single key, use `delete`.

`pickBy`, as the name implies, is meant for predicate-function-based picking (filtering) of items, which is not what `delete` does without a loop.

For instance, if your (fictitious) goal is to turn

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "quux",
  "beq": "berp",
  "uub": "uuzpq",
}
```

into

```
{
  "beq": "berp",
  "uub": "uuzpq",
}
```

i.e. where the key and value start with the same letter – who knows why you'd need that but that's beside the point, you'd have a worse time with a loop and `delete` than with `pickBy`.

Comment: Your example is very clearly